# Hide the save button in certain workstage

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to hide the save button if the form was **submitted** with the below configuration (properties-local):

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.button.save-draft.visible.*.*">
    xxf:instance('fr-workflow-stage-value') = "submitted"
</property>
```

I also tried with something like:

```
   xxf:instance('fb-form-instance')/xh:head/xf:model[@id = 'fr-form-model']/xf:bind[@id = 'fr-form-binds']/readonly = "true"
```

or:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.button.save-draft.visible.*.*">
   fr:workflow-stage-value() = "submitted"
</property>
```

But they didn't work. So could I get any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying which Orbeon Forms version you are using, but there is currently no internal instance called `fr-workflow-stage-value`, which probably explains why this is not working. The correct way to do this, since Orbeon Forms 2020.1, is to use the [`fr:workflow-stage-value()`](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-form-runner#fr-workflow-stage-value) function.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm in the latest version of orbeon. I already tried with below but it didn't work also:
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.button.save-draft.visible.*.*">
fr-workflow-stage-value() = "submitted"</property>

Comment: You have to write the function with the `fr:` prefix. It's missing in your code above.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. I already tried with your suggestion but it didn't work

Comment: Do you also run the `set-workflow-stage()` action somewhere to set the value to `submitted`?

Comment: Yes.@avernet Could you help me with it? :)

Comment: One thing I forgot: are you using a relational database? Workflow stages only work with those, but not with the embedded XML database.

Comment: Yes, It works for me with read-only form using the stage. But not for hiding the button

Comment: I am not sure why: it should work the same way. Can you hide the button if you use another XPath expression, like `true()` and `false()`, or something else?